# Not sure why body is center

Tags: html, css

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.

https://codepen.io/jadeite1000/pen/YzrmJRg

Not sure why my page is center.
I don't want it to be center.
I just want it to be left align.

```
                <body>
                <!--
                <h1>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h1>
                <h2>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h2>
                <h3>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h3>
                <h4>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h4>
                <h5>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h5>
                <h6>The Basic Language of the Web: HTML</h6>
                -->
                <div class="container">
                  <header class="main-header">
                <h1> The Code Magazine</h1>

                <nav>
                  <!-- <strong>This is the navigation</strong> -->
                  <a href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                  <a href="#">Challenges</a>
                  <a href="#">Flexbox</a>
                  <a href="#">CSS Grid</a>
                </nav>
```

[image]

Comment: You’ve got margin 0 auto on your container.

Comment: its because of the `container` class

Answer (score 3):

It's center-aligned because of `container` class

**auto:**
The browser selects a suitable margin to use. For example, in certain cases, this value can be used to center an element.

check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin#values

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */  // remove margin auto
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `container` ruleset you have added `margin: 0 auto;` which means `margin-top:0`, `margin-bottom:0`, `margin-left:auto`, `margin-right:auto`.

due to this `margin`, the ui came to the center.

Try removing `margin: 0 auto;` in `container` ruleset.